# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'txt' - Python Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was developing a new project to kinda move away from the most basic stuff I could do and I decided to look into web scraping.
My idea was to use [SteamStatus](https://www.steamstatus.io/) to check Steam's current status and have my script print it. For the first one, I was going with the Steam Store's status, and I've wrote the following code:

```
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://www.steamstatus.io/')
res.raise_for_status

SteamStatus = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.txt, 'html.parser')
type(SteamStatus)

storeStatus = SteamStatus.select('#statustables > div.statustable.left > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.statusrow_status.store-status')
print(str(storeStatus))
```

With this, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/a864/PycharmProjects/automation/steam status/webpage.py", line 8, in <module>
    SteamStatus = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.txt, 'html.parser')
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'txt'
```

From what I've searched and found, this would be a problem of outdated versions of the requests module but I've already made sure I have the latest version (2.24.0)

Comment: No, it would be because its meant to be `.text`, not `.txt` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception is telling you, you are attempting to refer to a nonexistent attribute.  The `Response` exposes a `.text` attribute, not a `.txt` attribute.

Comment: Ended up figuring that one out, thanks.
`[<div class="statusrow_status store-status">Loading</div>]` now my problem is that this is the output I'm getting. The "Loading" should actually be "Normal", "Delayed", etc and I know that while the site is loading, "loading" appears, is there any way I could make it only scrape after it has fully loaded? I've tried `time.sleep` already but went as far as 20 seconds (way more than it takes to load for me) but it still shows the "loading"

Comment: @Meirewes If you have a separate question, raise a separate question ... you might want to consider whether that status is being generated by javascript however ...

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO!

As specified in the previous answers, the error relates to the use of the wrong attribute `.txt` - in spite of the correct `.text`.

As a final note, the page you are trying to scrape is loaded with javascript, hence `requests` is not the package you are looking for. See below for a rough solution using `selenium` webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # initialize the driver

driver.get('https://www.steamstatus.io/') # go to the page

source = driver.page_source # extract the source

SteamPage = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

SteamStatus = SteamPage.findAll('div', {'class' : 'statusrow'})
for s in SteamStatus:
    print(s.findNext('div', {'class' : 'statusrow_name'}).text) # print the row name
    print(s.findNext('div', {'class' : 'statusrow_status'}).text) # and the uploaded value
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
SteamStatus = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.txt, 'html.parser')
```

try this one:

```
SteamStatus = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
```

the difference is the `res.txt` and `res.text`

Comment: This information has already been added in the accepted answer, make sure that whenever you post an answer, that it is not already said somewhere else.